# In Next.js: How to pass the async data fetched by getServerSideProps... to a component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

Thanks for hopping on the question! I'm still learning and might need you to explain it to me like I'm 5.

**What's working well:**

On my Homepage, I'm getting data from getServerSideProps and mapping it. The data is being fetched from a data.json within the project folder.

> export default function Homepage({ data }) { ... }
>
> export async function getServerSideProps() { ... }

Homepage has Mapping Function No. 1... This is working well for me!

**What I want to do:**

Now, I want to access the data that getServerSideProps() fetches, from inside of a component called ListComponent.

I want to be able to use original data again, in Mapping Function No. 2. I want this to happen inside of ListComponent.

ListComponent will then be imported to my Homepage.

**What didn't work:**

Inside of ListComponent, I tried passing in the same data that I was using on the Homepage, like this:

> export default function ListComponent({ data }) { ... }

It did not work. It says data is undefined, or that data cannot be read. Why is that? How can I pass the data to ListComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the data as props:

```
export default function Homepage({ data }) {
  return (
   // ...
   <ListComponent data={data} />
   // ...
  )
}
```

Now, you have data as `data` props:

```
export default function ListComponent({ data }) { 
  // play with data
}
```